# react hooks toggle for specific row

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, row, toggle

Please clarify my problem of toggle for specific row of the table with react hooks. whenever I press click.. it opens for every row and by default the table head is moving right it is not constant.

Error in toggleHidden(key).  How to correct my toggleHidden function?

```
const[isHidden , setIsHidden] = React.useState(true)

const toggleHidden = () => setIsHidden(!isHidden)

const data = [
    {
        "name": "gvf",
        "email": "abc",
        "companyname": "xyz",
        "address": "abcy"
    },
    {
      "name": "abi",
      "email": "dhf",
      "companyname": "dhd",
      "address": "fhfh"
    } 
]
  
     return (
       <div>
        <Row>
          <Col> 
           <table  className="table table-hover table-striped table-sm">
              <thead className="thead-dark">
                 <tr>
                   <th>Name</th>
                   <th>Email</th>
                   <th>CompanyName</th>
                   <th>Address</th>
                  
                 </tr>
                
             </thead>          
      <tbody>  
              
    
                 {data.map((a , key) => (
                   
                    <tr key={a.name}>
                <td><Button onClick = {toggleHidden(key)}>Click</Button>
         {!isHidden && <p>Hello ABIII</p> }
          </td>    
                        <td>{a.name}</td>
                        <td>{a.email}</td>
                        <td>{a.address}</td>
                        <td>{a.companyname}</td>
                     
                    </tr>


                  ))}
              </tbody>
         </table>
    </Col> 
</Row> </div>
```

Comment: Please don't post code into comments. [edit] the question instead.

Answer (score 1):

you need define the specific row - when You mapping:

```
     {data.map(a => (

      )}
```

try add key attribute to every item in collection like this:

```
        {data.map((a, key) => (
 
        ))}
```

then pass to Your item:

```
 <tr key={key}>
```

So now every  is unique - so if You pass that key to your function:

```
<Button onClick = {toggleHidden(key)}>
```

the program should know which specific item execute `toggleHidden` function

Comment: Not recommended to use the array index as the react key, can just use `a.name` like OP is already using.

Comment: Name can be duplicated - thus id not. Why not ? It’s checked solution for having sorted every mapping items? (1,2,3 ... 888, 889, 890) If items doesn’t have id prop from backend this is only method.

Comment: OP is already using `name` without mention of any react unique key warnings. Please review [React Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) or specifically the [in-depth explanation on the negative impacts of using an index as a key](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318).

Comment: Thanks - so U recommend when not id exist then generate them on fe side ?

Comment: Yes, when receiving array data with elements without any guaranteed unique properties it is advisable to generate and add a unique identifier, or GUID, to each element that won't change during the life of the data being rendered.