# Toggle specific row with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, row, toggle

Error in toggleHidden(key) [error: expecting 0 args but got 1] . kindly suggest corrections top toggle with key for particular row.

`code`

```
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);
```

const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

const[isHidden , setIsHidden] = React.useState(true)

const toggleHidden = () => setIsHidden(!isHidden)

```
 const data = [
{
    "name": "gvf",
    "email": "abc",
    "companyname": "xyz",
    "address": "abcy"
},

{
  "name": "abi",
  "email": "dhf",
  "companyname": "dhd",
  "address": "fhfh"
```

}

]

```
   return (
   <div>
    <Row>
      <Col> 
       <table  className="table table-hover table-striped table-sm">
          <thead className="thead-dark">
             <tr>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Email</th>
               <th>CompanyName</th>
               <th>Address</th>
              
             </tr>
            
         </thead>    
 <tbody>  
          

             {data.map((a , key) => (
               
                <tr key={key}>
            <td><Button onClick = {toggleHidden}>Click</Button>
     {!isHidden && <p>Hello ABIII</p> }
      </td>    
                    <td>{a.name}</td>
                    <td>{a.email}</td>
                    <td>{a.address}</td>
                    <td>{a.companyname}</td>
                 
                </tr>


              ))}
          </tbody>
     </table>
 </Col>
```

)
  
  }

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be sufficiently different from your other question [react hooks toggle for specific row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63186731/react-hooks-toggle-for-specific-row). Please update the original question if you've further issues or it isn't being resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the state to be an array and "pop"/"push" keys into it on toggle, then declare a curried handler that accepts a key, and performs proper toggle logic. I removed `isOpen` state since it was not used in the example, however you can change it the same way that `isHidden` state and toggler was changed:

```
const [ isHiddenList, setIsHiddenList ] = React.useState([])
const toggleHidden = key => () => {
        setIsHiddenList(
            isHiddenList.includes(key)
                ? isHiddenList.filter(existingKey => existingKey !== key)
                : [ ...isHiddenList, key ]
        );
};

const data = [
    {
        "key": "1"
        "name": "gvf",
        "email": "abc",
        "companyname": "xyz",
        "address": "abcy"
    },
    {
        "key": "2"
        "name": "abi",
        "email": "dhf",
        "companyname": "dhd",
        "address": "fhfh"
    }
]

return (
    <div>
        <Row>
            <Col> 
                <table  className="table table-hover table-striped table-sm">
                    <thead className="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>CompanyName</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>    
                    <tbody>  
                        {
                            data.map(({ key, name, email, companyname, address }) => {
                                const isHidden = isHiddenList.includes(key);
                                return (
                                    <tr key={key}>
                                        <td><Button onClick={toggleHidden(key)}>Click</Button>
                                        {!isHidden && <p>Hello ABIII</p> }
                                        </td>    
                                        <td>{a.name}</td>
                                        <td>{a.email}</td>
                                        <td>{a.address}</td>
                                        <td>{a.companyname}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                );
                            })
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </div>
)
```

**disclaimer** - key should be part of data items for consistency, dynamically generated iteration index does not guarantee that keys will be assigned properly.